# running .bat in powershell script without opening any windows

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, command-prompt

I have written a PowerShell script that is going to interpret a mail's body for command's and create a `.bat` file to execute the commando's it found.
This script works, but the one big issues is that whenever is executes the `.bat` file, a command-prompt window flashes over the screen real quick. I was wondering if it's possible to prevent this from happening?

### My code:

```
$m.Body | Out-File cmd.bat -Encoding ascii -Append
.\cmd.bat | Out-File results.txt
```

Is there any command of property i have to set?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers and information can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/140047/how-to-run-a-batch-file-without-launching-a-command-window/390129).

From there, the selected answer, in case the link goes stale:

> Save the following as wscript, for instance, hidecmd.vbs after replacing "testing.bat" with your batch file's name.

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") 
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "cmd /c testing.bat"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

> The second parameter of oShell.Run is intWindowStyle value indicating the appearance of the program's window and zero value is for hidden window.
>
> The reference is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky.aspx

Comment: I'm using PowerShell, not vba. Don't think syntax is applicable?

Comment: @TomKustermans Perhaps not the syntax, but I would think it possible to do essentially the same thing in PowerShell - create a windows script interpreter and execute its `Run` command. Oh what the heck, let me Google it for you: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_com.htm

Comment: It worked: PowerShell syntax: 
`$WSH = New-Object -Com WScript.Shell`
and run .bat with :
`$WSH.Run("cmd.bat",0) | Out-File results.txt` 0 parameter indicating it's hidden window indeed ;) thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is more than 2 years old at the time I write this however there is still no official answer.  Although I am very new to PowerShell, I think I have a more pure Powershell answer than using vbscript or COM.

Use Invoke Command:

```
Invoke-Command {cmd.exe /c cmd.bat} | Out-File results.txt
```

That Should do the trick.  This will shell to cmd.exe and the /c will self terminate the shell on completion.  It will run within the current shell so no new window will open.